# Javascript Infovis Toolkit's Spacetree sample not working locally

Tags: javascript, visualization, infovis, thejit, space-tree

Trying to make custom tree animation based on InfoVis toolkit, and to be particular, want to customize Spacetree [Tree animation sample](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html). For that reason, saved sample to local computer, however opening local sample is not working properly, i.e. the outcome is not exactly same with web version. Firstly, the nodes are not colored, secondly, there is no response for onClick event. I've checked both local and web versions of html files, everything is same, all js and css files are properly called and accessible. Anyone had similar problems? Please share the solution if you have. Thanks in advance.

screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you do any change in your local version? If yes, then what?  And how did you save this example locally? did you download the whole JIT package from the jit site?

Comment: No, I didn't make any changes to source files. I saved html files locally by using browser's 'Save page as' function. And do I have to download JIT package to run this sample locally? I guess the sample already has jit-yc.js and example1.js files, I was thinking these are enough.

Comment: I've played the with the package, yes, as you said it works well in its own webserver, but whenever I try to save locally, the outcome is the same. You may wonder, why I'm obsessed with saving the example visualization locally. I want to first develop and customize in my local environment, after that upload to my hosting. I'm not sure that if it is not working on my local environment it will work in my web-site.

Comment: Strange that I didn't check the library itself first. I was playing with their custom build option [here](https://github.com/philogb/jit/wiki/Getting-Started). The problem is solved, thank you very much. If you add an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you download the package. It contains all the examples to play with for all visualizations. And in my package, the example that you are referring to works fine.

So, you don't have to create local copies the way you are creating. Just download the toolkit and you have local copies of all the examples including the one you want. In fact, you can create as many local copies as you want from the toolkit.